# Make an antd transfer larger with css

Tags: css, resize, jsx, antd, transfer

I need to use a transfer component from antd for a page, but the default size is way too small.  I have tried to change it using the listStyle and style attributes.  I've read through the documentation and don't see any other style options.  When it's rendered, I can see that I need to change the size of the "ant-transfer-list"

```
<TransferComponent
        style={{
            height:1000
        }}
        listStyle={{
          width: 1000,
          height: 1000,
        }}
        formattedInput={this.state.formattedObjectTypes} 
        onSelectChange={this.onSelectChange} 
        sourceName="Available" 
        targetName="Selected"
        />
```

My jsx is as shown.  I've tried both height:1000 and height:"1000px" with no change on either listStyle or style.

Answer (score 2):

The property **listStyle** works for me:

```
<Transfer
    listStyle={{width: 500}}
/>
```